# How does magazine publishing work on the Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, application-development, pdf

I'm looking into publishing a magazine on the Ubuntu Software Center, how would I go about doing that?

I notice there are a lot of them, but I'm not sure how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about magazines, but I published my app through the MyApps service.
They will package your magazine, so you do not need to provide the debian package.
I should take a look at the [Ubuntu developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/).

After installing Full Circle Magazine #53 and launching it's icon from dash, Nautilus opened in `/opt/fullcircle/issues` and it contained `fullcircle-issue53-eng.pdf`.

The thing I know for sure is that your magazine must be in `/opt`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already know how to do that, I'm just wondering how the specifics work. For example, I dont know if I can just supply a pdf or if I have to create an app to loead the pdf.

Comment: Install some magazine and look if it opens in Evince PDF Viewer or it has its own app.